# Error when using Google appsmarket/v2/licenseNotification API - "Temporary error. Please try later."

Tags: python, google-api, google-apps-marketplace, google-api-python-client

We have Google Apps Marketplace application, and we periodically run the following request, to get all granted licenses:

> https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/licenseNotification/appId?max-results=1000&timestamp=0&alt=json

This was working fine for over a year, but recently (since Apr. 29th 2015) we started receiving consistently the following error (using python lib to access the API):

> apiclient.errors.HttpError: HttpError 503 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/licenseNotification/appId?max-results=1000&timestamp=0&alt=json returned "Temporary error. Please try later."

Did this happen to anyone else ? Did Google change anything in the authentication process ?

Comment: I had the same problem. Don't use timestamp=0, use a timestamp 1 year ago or more recent.

Comment: What error code do you get?

Comment: @qtxo - tried using a specific timestamp from a couple of months ago, still getting the same error.

Comment: @Gerardo - I get HTTP error 503

Comment: Now I am seeing the same error, not every request fails.

Comment: Opened a support ticket with Google, waiting for their answer/resolution

Comment: Google acknowledged this to be a bug, they're working on a fix...